# How to handle Up Button Action Bar passing a variable

Tags: android, android-activity

I'd love to get some answer, thanks!

Well, what I want to do it's simple.

I have an activity which displays on the screen some projects of a team, to this activity fill the projects in the recycler view, it has to get a variable like "idTeam" (bacause I show only the projects that belongs to a specified team). Let's call this activity by HomeTeamActivity.

In this activity, I have also a toolbar with a menu, and in this menu I have a option that leaves the user to an another activity. Let's call this activity by SecondActivity.

Okay, I've implemented an Up Button in this SecondActivity, to leaves the user to the HomeTeamActivity, and this works fine, BUT, to the HomeTeamActivity works properly, it has to get the "idTeam". My problem is here, I'm trying to pass this variable from the SecondActivity to the HomeTeamAcitivity, but I can't handle this Up Button.

I've read a lot of questions here in Stackoverflow about it, but none could help me.
I tried to overide the method "onOptionsItemSelected" like the code below, but when I click in the up button, nothing happens. I tried to insert a breakpoint on the "switch case" statement of this method, and the debugger doesn't get in.

My manifest file is ok I guess, because if I remove the method "onOptionsItemSelected", the Up Button leaves the user to the HomeTeamActivity, but without passing the variable that I need.

The code of the SecondActivity is below:

```
public class AddMembroEquipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String idEquipe;
    private String nomeEquipe;
    private String descEquipe;
    private DatabaseReference mRefUsuario;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private EditText mTextoPesquisa;
    private Button mPesquisar;
    //Texto que o usuário digitou no campo
    private String stringPesquisa;

    //Infos do usuário que está logado
    String emailUsuarioLogado;
    String idUsuarioLogado;

    //Lista que guarda os usuários recebidos da pesquisa
    private List<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>();




    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.home:
                Log.d("backbutton", "cheguei");
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddMembroEquipeActivity.this, ProjetosEquipeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("idEquipe", idEquipe);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }


        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_membro_equipe);
        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar tbAddMembrosEquipe = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_addMembrosEquipe);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(bundle !=null) {
            idEquipe = bundle.getString("idEquipe");
            nomeEquipe = bundle.getString("nomeEquipe");
            descEquipe = bundle.getString("desEquipe");
        }

        tbAddMembrosEquipe.setTitle("Adicionar Membros - " + nomeEquipe );

        mRefUsuario = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usuarios");

        mTextoPesquisa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pesquisa);
        mPesquisar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_pesquisar);

        setSupportActionBar(tbAddMembrosEquipe);

        if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
}
```

I hope the question in clear and that my english can be understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `R.id.home` with `android.R.id.home`

Something like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        ....
        ....   
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Ohhh... Thanks Thanks thanks!!! I can't believe that it was a so simple mistake, thanks again!!!